# The delegate method "clickedButtonAtIndex:" is not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have created an alert view with two buttons using the following code:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title 
message: msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Replay" otherButtonTitles:@"Highscore", nil];
[alertView show];
```

I want to run some code when one of the buttons is clicked.
In order to do so, I have added the following method to the delegate.m file:

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 if (buttonIndex==0) //Run some code 
 else //Other code
 }
```

But this method is not called when I press either of the buttons!
Can someone tell me why?

Thanks in advance,

Sagiftw

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
delegate:nil
```

how will the alert view associate a delegate if you specified there will be no delegates? Replace that part with

```
delegate:self
```

instead.

Comment: Thanx i was also forgot that.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the delegate to self instead of nil.

Answer (score 2):

I was calling UIAlertView's **dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:** method from UITextField delegate method because I wanted to handle the keyboard return key as well:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.tag == 1001) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [_alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This way method **alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:** never gets called even if you set up proper delegate. Instead **alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:** does get called. So implement this method instead:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // your code here
}
```

If you just want to handle alert view's buttons only, those first call clickedButtonAtIndex and then didDismissWithButtonIndex.

Answer (score 0):

in .h put UIActionSheetDelegate and in .m while creating a alertView put the delegate to self not nil as being done in the above case

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for this question is `delegate:nil`. But in case that the delegate is already set to self, and the `clickedButtonAtIndex` is still not working, try checking if you are popping another view controller (`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`) after showing the alertview. This can also result to `clickedButtonAtIndex` not being called. This is what happened to me.

Hope this helps someone.