# Don't Pop Navigation Controller in Xcode if AlertView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

I have a `Navigation Controller` and when I press the back button I don't want to pop the view but I want to show an `UIAlertView`.I just want to pop the view after having make a choice on the `UIAlertView`!
How can I do?
I tried to catch the event 'back button pressed' but with no results :(

Comment: do you want pop up viewcontroller? or display alertview on button action?

Comment: create a back button with custom method of showing the alert and add to navbar implement pop in the alertviewdelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a UIBarButtonItem inside **viewDidload** and added it to the navigation bar

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backButton;
```

create a method which will be called when the backButton is clicked

```
-(void)backButtonClicked{
       UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pop View!" message:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
       [alert show];
}
```

write this UIAlertView delegate method which will be called when the button in the UIAlertView is clicked

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
      if (buttonIndex==1) {
             [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      }
}
```

**NOTE**: Dont forget to add UIAlertView delegate in the header file `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Comment: Ok I think this is the correct way and It works perfectly! Is it possible to make the UIBarButtonItem looks like the Back Button?

Comment: You can. One way to do is to use a custom image.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for back-button press in the `viewWillDisappear` method like this (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller/3445994#3445994)):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound && self.isBackButtonPressed) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
        // in the navigation stack.
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would be nice if you mentioned the source with a link to the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3445994/876283

Comment: You are right, I had this in my own code, and forgot the source.

Answer (score 0):

Implement pop in UIAlertview delegate method clickedButtonAtIndex:
The back button press need to implement only showing the UIAlertview

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537993/the-delegate-method-clickedbuttonatindex-is-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

follow this code

in button action.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Do you want to open?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
[alert show];

//Alert View delegate method
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)//NO
    {
        //your code
    }
    else if(buttonIndex==1)//YES
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```